# Django authenticationform and active users

Tags: django, django-authentication

If I change a current user's status to inactive, they are not able to login. This is expected. However, the error message they receive is to enter in a proper username and password. I expect that they should get the inactive login message.

I am subclassing the authentication form:

```
class CustomAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    """Sub-class authentication form to remove whitespace"""

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        username = ''.join(username.split())
        password = " ".join(password.split())
        if username is not None and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(
                self.request, username=username, password=password)
            print("tried again")
            if self.user_cache is None:
                print("self cache")
                raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
            else:
                print("self confirm")
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data
```

When I try to log in as a user that has a username and password but it now inactive, the `tried again` and `self cache` get printed to the console. Since the user is inactive I would expect the `self confirm` statement to be printed to the console, and this would lead to the `confirm_login_allowed` function and the correct ValidationError.

For what its worth, I am subsclassing this form because I had some users that could not login using their Android phone - their web browser was inserting whitespace. My CustomAuthenticationForm removes this whitespace.

**edit: I have done some more testing.**
I create a very basic django app with only home, login and logout pages. Stock auth views, forms.  I created a new user, logged in as admin and made the user inactive.  I then tried to login as that user. I got the same message "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.".

Either I don't quite understand how this is supposed to work, or this is broken? New install of django so probably Django 4.1

Comment: It sounds stupid, because it is, but are you **1000%** sure `authenticate` is getting a valid username+password pair? I find it's usually something dumb like that.

Comment: I am sure I have the correct username and password.

Answer (score 0):

In [backends.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/backends.py) (django/contrib/auth) if line 48 is changed from:

```
if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
```

to

```
if user.check_password(password):
```

Then if a user exists but is inactive, they will get the error message `This account is inactive.`  If a user exists and is active, they log in. This is what I originally expected to happen.

My next question is what exactly is the expected behaviour of this from the developers' point of view? I feel like I would expect and want this change but maybe there are other situations where it breaks something.

**EDIT**
It turns out that there was a [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28645) about this. I believe it is seen as a security threat.